# Asking for encrypt or multiple encrypt, then asking for decrypt or exit

Tags: python, encryption

I am making a program that encrypts text to a file, then saves the file in whatever directory python is saved to. In the process I had the bright idea to have the program ask if the user wants to continue with more encrypts, or stopping. Now I have the even brighter idea of asking if they then want to move to decrypt or exit, however I am having issues with how the could should work. I have about a months and half worth of experience, so keeping it simple, without using def() or things like that would be appreciated.

Edit: I have now gotten all the code to work properly except for the very end in the else statement. I would like to give the user the option to retry their spelling input or exit the program. Having a hard time figuring out how to do that

```
#Input asking for encrypt or decrypt 
question = input("Are you Encrypting or Decrypting?: ")
encryptResult = ""

#While loop for multiple encrypts
while True:

#If statement for encrypt
    if question == 'Encrypting':

        #statements telling the user the choice they made
        print("So, you have chosen to encrpyt, very well then, lets hide some secrets.")

        #Asks user for phrase to encrypt
        encryptText = input("Enter the phrase you wish to encrypt, if you dare: ")

        #Asks user for file to save to
        createFile = input("Enter the file name you wish to save to: ")

        #For loop converting to ascii and adding 1
        for ch in encryptText:
            encryptValue = ord(ch) + 1
            bString = ""

            #While loop for conversion to binary
            while encryptValue > 0:
                remainder = encryptValue % 2
                encryptValue = encryptValue // 2
                bString = str(remainder) + bString

            #If statement moving characters to the left 1 time
            if len(bString) > 0:
                bString = bString[1:] + bString[0]
                encryptResult += bString + " "

        #File variables opening and creating a file, writing, then closing.
        filecontent = open(createFile, 'w')
        filecontent.write(encryptResult)
        filecontent.close()
        print("The deed is done, your secrets are now encrypted and safe from prying eyes.")

    #Ask the user if they would encrypt another message
        again = input("Would you like to encrypt another message? Yes or No? ")

    #If elif for another encrypt or stopping
        if again == 'Yes':
            continue
        elif again == 'No':              
            pass                      
        
        #Ask the user if they would like to decrypt now
        decryptNow = input("Would you like to decrypt now or exit the program? Decrypt or Exit? ")

        #if and elif for decrypting now
        if decryptNow == 'Decrypt':
            question = 'Decrypting'      

        elif decryptNow == 'Exit':
            break        
  
    #elif for decrypt    
    elif question == 'Decrypting':

            #Print statement after choosing decrypt
            print("Time to reveal some secrets, lets get decrypting.")

            #input varaible asking for the file to decrypt
            message = input("Enter the secret you wish to decrypt: ")

            #File varaibles opening the input, splitting, adding to list
                #and then plaintext

            decryptfile = open(message, 'r')
            code = decryptfile.read()
            wordList = code.split()
            plaintext = ""

            #For loop for shifting to the right 1 character, converting to decimal
            #removing 1 from ascii value, then converting to string and storing
            #to variable 
            for eachPass in wordList:
                eachPass = eachPass[-1] + eachPass[:-1]
                decimal = 0
                exponent = len(eachPass) - 1
                for digit in eachPass:
                    decimal = decimal + int(digit) * 2 ** exponent
                    exponent = exponent - 1

                decimal -= 1
                plaintext += chr(decimal)

            #Close file and print decoded message
            decryptfile.close()
            print(plaintext)
        
            #Ask if they wish to decrypt another message or exit
            decryptAgain = input("Please input Continue to continue decrypting, Exit to exit the program, or Encrypt to go back to encrypting secrets. Please use proper spelling.")

            if decryptAgain == 'Continue':
                continue
            elif decryptAgain == 'Exit':
                break
            elif decryptAgain == 'Encrypt':
                question = 'Encrypting'
    #If neither encrypt or decrypt is chosen, tell them to try again
    else:
        print("Error, please relaunch program and use 'Encrypting' or 'Decrypting' with proper spelling.")
        break
    
            #also would like to loop back to start if wrong button or spelling used
            #currently it just ends program
        
#Keep program open until button is pressed
print(input("Press the Alt + F4 key to exit the program."))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you are asking how to break out of a loop: You can do that with `break`.

Comment: I know that and i realizedd it soon after, however if you reply yes to ```decryptNow = input("Would you like to decrypt now or exit the program? Yes or Exit? ")``` it just exits the program, then if you press another button it loops back to the encrypt part of the loop. I don't really need all this fancy stuff to be going on but I would like to know how to do it. also typing Exit takes you back to the beginning of the loop as well

Comment: There are some issues with the indentation in that part of your code (i.e. `if decryptNow == 'Exit'` should be on the same indentation level as `if decryptNow == 'Yes':`). Keep in mind that python is whitespace-sensitive, so different amount of indentations give the program different meanings. If you could fix these formatting issues please, that would make the program easier to analyze. Also, my understanding is that when `decryptNow == 'Yes'`, you should update `question` to `Decrypting`, otherwise the if statement below that will not be entered.

Comment: How do i update ```question``` if the user types Yes for ```decryptNow == 'Yes'```. I suppose thats where im getting hung up. If you type yes it just loops to ```again = input("Would you like to encrypt another message? Yes or No? ")``` instead of continuing to decrypt portion

Comment: You could replace the pass below `if decryptNow == 'Yes':` with `question = "Decrypting"`.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 that worked thank you, but now it just loops the decrypting forever instead of ending the program after the first decrypt

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem of the decrypting loop. I think you might already have solved it with the current version of the code? Regarding the question of retrying when the user misspelled. There are of course many ways of doing this, here is one suggestion: At the beginning of the program, set `question = None` and remove the `input(...)` part. Then in your loop, you can add a check `if question == None:` and below that you can query the user input. In the final `else` where you catch spelling mistakes, you can set `question = None` again. Like this: https://pastebin.com/61LH9u8Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code after editing to check for wrong spelling without much modifications. It just needed to set question to `Spelling` and then check it in the next round for getting new input. You also had one check that was redundant and not needed at all which is:

```
elif again == 'No':
    pass
```

```
# Input asking for encrypt or decrypt
question = input("Are you Encrypting or Decrypting?: ")
encryptResult = ""

# While loop for multiple encrypts
while True:

    # If statement for encrypt
    if question == 'Encrypting':

        # statements telling the user the choice they made
        print("So, you have chosen to encrpyt, very well then, lets hide some secrets.")

        # Asks user for phrase to encrypt
        encryptText = input("Enter the phrase you wish to encrypt, if you dare: ")

        # Asks user for file to save to
        createFile = input("Enter the file name you wish to save to: ")

        # For loop converting to ascii and adding 1
        for ch in encryptText:
            encryptValue = ord(ch) + 1
            bString = ""

            # While loop for conversion to binary
            while encryptValue > 0:
                remainder = encryptValue % 2
                encryptValue = encryptValue // 2
                bString = str(remainder) + bString

            # If statement moving characters to the left 1 time
            if len(bString) > 0:
                bString = bString[1:] + bString[0]
                encryptResult += bString + " "

        # File variables opening and creating a file, writing, then closing.
        filecontent = open(createFile, 'w')
        filecontent.write(encryptResult)
        filecontent.close()
        print("The deed is done, your secrets are now encrypted and safe from prying eyes.")

        # Ask the user if they would encrypt another message
        again = input("Would you like to encrypt another message? Yes or No? ")

        # If elif for another encrypt or stopping
        if again == 'Yes':
            continue

        # This check is not needed
        # elif again == 'No':
        #     pass

            # Ask the user if they would like to decrypt now
        decryptNow = input("Would you like to decrypt now or exit the program? Decrypt or Exit? ")

        # if and elif for decrypting now
        if decryptNow == 'Decrypt':
            question = 'Decrypting'

        elif decryptNow == 'Exit':
            break

            # elif for decrypt
    elif question == 'Decrypting':

        # Print statement after choosing decrypt
        print("Time to reveal some secrets, lets get decrypting.")

        # input varaible asking for the file to decrypt
        message = input("Enter the secret you wish to decrypt: ")

        # File varaibles opening the input, splitting, adding to list
        # and then plaintext

        decryptfile = open(message, 'r')
        code = decryptfile.read()
        wordList = code.split()
        plaintext = ""

        # For loop for shifting to the right 1 character, converting to decimal
        # removing 1 from ascii value, then converting to string and storing
        # to variable
        for eachPass in wordList:
            eachPass = eachPass[-1] + eachPass[:-1]
            decimal = 0
            exponent = len(eachPass) - 1
            for digit in eachPass:
                decimal = decimal + int(digit) * 2 ** exponent
                exponent = exponent - 1

            decimal -= 1
            plaintext += chr(decimal)

        # Close file and print decoded message
        decryptfile.close()
        print(plaintext)

        # Ask if they wish to decrypt another message or exit
        decryptAgain = input(
            "Please input Continue to continue decrypting, Exit to exit the program, or Encrypt to go back to encrypting secrets. Please use proper spelling.")

        if decryptAgain == 'Continue':
            continue
        elif decryptAgain == 'Exit':
            break
        elif decryptAgain == 'Encrypt':
            question = 'Encrypting'

    # If neither encrypt or decrypt is chosen, tell them to try again
    elif question == "Spelling":
        question = input("Error, please relaunch program and use 'Encrypting' or 'Decrypting' with proper spelling.")
    else:
        question = "Spelling"
        # also would like to loop back to start if wrong button or spelling used
        # currently it just ends program
        
# Keep program open until button is pressed
# This should be any key not Alt + F4
print(input("Press any key to exit the program."))
```